# Detect vim, less, etc. in Terminal

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, osx-yosemite

In OS X Yosemite's Terminal app, you can now scroll in vim/less/whatever using the mouse. How would one go about detecting whether the running program supports such scrolling?

Comment: Do you mean how do you detect it in code?

Comment: Or, more generally: Detect it from where?

Comment: Let's say I'm making my own Terminal app. How would I make a feature like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yosemite Terminal listens for the Alternate Screen escape sequences. If you go to Preferences→Settings→Keyboard, you can see the “Scroll alternate screen” option.

For more on xterm's Alternate Screen feature:

> In VT102 mode, there are escape sequences to activate and deactivate
>   an alternate screen buffer, which is the same size as the display area
>   of the window. When activated, the current screen is saved and
>   replaced with the alternate screen. Saving of lines scrolled off the
>   top of the window is disabled until the normal screen is restored. The
>   termcap(5) entry for xterm allows the visual editor vi(1) to switch to
>   the alternate screen for editing and to restore the screen on exit.

Answer (score 7):

The program that wants to support scrolling sends an escape sequence to the terminal enabling mouse input, e.g., `\e[?1002h` for reporting button clicks. Then the terminal sends control codes back to the program whenever you click the mouse, telling it which button you clicked and where. Scrolling up or down is sent as mouse clicks of buttons 4 and 5.

See the “Mouse Tracking” section starting around page 29 of the 
[XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.pdf) document.

Try this in bash:

```
$ echo $'\e[?1002h'
$ hexdump -C
... click and scroll a bit, then hit enter...
^[[Ma7*^[[Ma7*^[[M`7*^[[M`7*^[[M`7*^[[M`7*^[[Ma7*^[[Ma7*^[[M`1.^[[M`1.
00000000  1b 5b 4d 61 37 2a 1b 5b  4d 61 37 2a 1b 5b 4d 60  |.[Ma7*.[Ma7*.[M`|
00000010  37 2a 1b 5b 4d 60 37 2a  1b 5b 4d 60 37 2a 1b 5b  |7*.[M`7*.[M`7*.[|
00000020  4d 60 37 2a 1b 5b 4d 61  37 2a 1b 5b 4d 61 37 2a  |M`7*.[Ma7*.[Ma7*|
^C
Returned 130 (SIGINT).
```

The program that’s initiated mouse tracking—in this case, bash—receives mouse input as encoded stuff on standard input.

The open-source [MouseTerm plugin](https://github.com/brodie/mouseterm/) has been enabling scrolling in Terminal.app for a decade. You can take a look at its source code for details.

Comment: That might not be the story with less, however. less doesn't support mouse reporting (AFAIK), but various X terminal emulators and recent versions of tmux send VT cursor up/down signals upon scroll when it's running. I know it's the case with tmux that it looks to see if the alternate screen buffer (see that same XTerm resource) is active.

Comment: @andrewdotn I put those two commands in a script, ran the script, and scrolled, but I didn't get any output. Any ideas?